# How to save a channels file to a format that can be emailed?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpg, cs3

I have a PSD file in channels and want to convert (flatten?) it to something I can email to a client to show progress on the design. How is this done?

Comment: It would be easier to EXPORT as a `.pdf` but what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

With multi channel artwork, the easiest way I have found to provide a quicky overview is to just go into <kbd>View > Full Screen Mode</kbd> and take a screenshot. That will save yourself a lot of headaches, but the quality won't be great.

If the extra channels are spot colors, you can always select the spot channel(s) and select <kbd>Merge Spot Channel</kbd>:

[image]

The results from Merging the Spot Channel aren't always that pleasing though.

You can save as a PDF, but by default, Adobe Reader won't display the spot channels.